# How do I search and replace using a loop data in 2 data frame?

Tags: r

For example

I am reading a csv file

```
readURL = "https://storage.googleapis.com/covid19-open-data/v2/vaccinations.csv"
```

CRV Sample Shown Below

```
    Date        Code
1 2020-01-20     AL99
2 2020-01-20     AL9
3 2020-01-20     IO
4 2020-01-20     AL

Frame = read.csv(url(readURL))
```

I can search and manually change any text with AL in the dataframe using this method

```
Frame$key=gsub(".*AL.*", "Albania", Frame$key, perl=TRUE)
```

But I have another csv file with country codes. I don't want to manually write above code for all countries. how do I search using below dataframe code and replace using a loop?

```
readCountryURL = "https://pkgstore.datahub.io/core/country-list/data_csv/data/d7c9d7cfb42cb69f4422dec222dbbaa8/data_csv.csv"
```

CRV Sample Shown Below

```
    Name        Code
1 Afghanistan    AF
2 Albania        AL
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a solution using `str_replace_all` from `stringr` package.

However, I noticed that keys can have characters which are more than just the country code. For example, there are keys like `"BR_PR"`, `"BR_PR_412770"` and others. In the country code dataframe you have BR for Brazil and PR for puerto rico. This can be confusing so while matching I have kept only the keys till the 1st underscore so that `"BR_PR"` matches `"BR"` and the same with `"BR_PR_412770"`.

```
readURL = "https://storage.googleapis.com/covid19-open-data/v2/vaccinations.csv" 
Frame = read.csv(readURL)


readCountryURL = "https://pkgstore.datahub.io/core/country-list/data_csv/data/d7c9d7cfb42cb69f4422dec222dbbaa8/data_csv.csv"
country <- read.csv(readCountryURL, na.strings = '')


library(stringr)
Frame$country <- str_replace_all(str_remove(Frame$key, '_.*'), 
                                 setNames(country$Name, country$Code))
```

Use `Frame$key` in place of `Frame$country` if you want to replace the original `Frame$key` column.

Comment: Did you try running the code in my answer? My code already does that.